# jQuery countdown continue after date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-countdown

I'm using this fantastic jQuery code here:
http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

I'm trying to make it work after the ending date.
Do you have any idea?
It should display something like:

> 3 semaines soit 10 heures et 10 minutes

```
$('#timeout').countdown(finalDate, {elapse: true})
.countdown("2015/05/01 12:00:00", function(event) {
     $(this).text(
       event.strftime('%-w %!w:semaine,semaines; soit %-D %!D:jour,jours; et %-H %!H:heure,heures;')
   );
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: what problem are you  facing?

Comment: I think I don't get how to make it work the way I need because nothing displays... I don't know JS very well and can't really understand how to use that... Here's an example but it doesn't fit my needs: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/count-up.html

Comment: ok the example works pretty neatly. What is your requirement?

Comment: I need to specify a counting from date. Something like 2015/05/01 12:00:00 in order to see the countdown going from this date to now ! Pretty hard to adapt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code.

Use the example given in the [Doc](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html), it works perfectly if you write it like this:

```
  $('#timeout').countdown("2015/05/05 12:00:00", {elapse: true})
               .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
                   $(this).text(
                       event.strftime('%-w %!w:semaine,semaines; soit %-D %!D:jour,jours; et %-H %!H:heure,heures;')
                   );
                });
```

I made a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odubuc/o7dje5gj/) as an exemple